# добавить в массив JS

Tags: javascript

доброго времени!

```
 var opt_cat_serv=[];
  for(i=0;i<this.kol_category_service;i++){
        opt_cat_serv=["option",[["value",this.mas_category_service[i]['id_category']]],this.mas_category_service[i]['name']];
    }


  mas_table[0][2].push(["tr",false,[
      ["td",false,"Категория"],
      ["td",false,[
        ["select",[["name","service_category"]],[
          ["option",[["value","0"]],"Выбирите категорию"],
          opt_cat_serv
         ]]
       ]],
     ]]);
```

у меня в цикле  должен получится массив категорий с id и названием. После мне нужно добавить в массив  `mas_table[0][2]` данные о новых категориях, но добавляется только одна. (этот массив формирует select форму)

Если делаю так `opt_cat_serv[i]` в цикле,  то получаю ошибку. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле слишком много массивов внутри массивов массивов. Но проблема проста, нужно заменить `=` на вызов метода `push`

```
for(i=0;i<this.kol_category_service;i++){
    opt_cat_serv.push(["option",[["value",this.mas_category_service[i]['id_category']]],this.mas_category_service[i]['name']]);
}
```